# return list and iqueryable in c#

Tags: c#, api, web

I have a task Web API in C#, so my task is that I have to return from a MY SQL database person information who's salary is more than a Integer which user has to type and lives in the city which user has to type.

and i have these classes:

[image: Personclass]
[image: AddressClass]

So I have tried to do it with Linq but somehow it does not work, says that
"Error  CS0019  Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'bool' "
Can you help me and tell me which _context.Persons.Where
commant i should use for searching in database 2 things salary and city which we are looking for.
Thanks in advance

[image: Address]

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you're assigning instead of comparing the property `x.Address.City = someCity`. If you want to compare, then you need to use the Equality operator `==` e.g `x.Address.City == someCity`.

Comment: return _context.Persons.Where(x => x.Address.City == someCity&& x.Salary >param);


this one does not work either

Comment: What specific error are you getting now or why is it not working?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Homework17_ORM.Domain.Person>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<Homework17_ORM.Domain.Person>' Homework17

Comment: Okay, so specifically, this is because there's a mismatch between what your function is returning (a list of persons) and what you have declared the return type of your function is.

Comment: Do you know the command which can help me for these, i mean i have to check the city where that person is living and salary should be more than a certain amount in entity framework, so i could not find any solution how do i check these